# How to add columns to input matrix without shrinking matrix size in r shiny?

Tags: r, user-interface, matrix, shiny, user-input

Whenever I add columns to the matrix, the columns shrink in width until they become way too small. Is there a way to increase the width of the page so that the matrix columns don't shrink? Thanks

```
  output$mat <- renderUI({
        rw<-list(1:input$numoc)
        for (i in (1:input$numoc)) {
            rw[[1]][[i]] = paste("Outcome", i, sep=" ")
        }
 

        clm<-list(1:input$inp1)
        for (i in (1:input$inp1)) {
            clm[[1]][[i]] = paste("Treatment", i, sep=" ")
        }

        matrix1 <- matrix(seq(from=1, to=((input$numoc)*(input$inp1)), by=1), input$inp1, input$numoc, dimnames = list(clm[[1]],rw[[1]]))
        
        matrixInput("mat", "Probabilities", matrix1, rows=list(names=TRUE), cols=list(names=TRUE))
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is possible using CSS. Once we have overwritten `table-layout: fixed;` of the HTML element  `table` the header cells respond to the `min-width` attribute. You can adapt the minimum width to your needs.

Make sure you use the correct `inputID` to select the HTML table. In CSS the ID is preceded by `#`.

Disadvantage (of course): at some point you get a horizontal scroll bar.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(
        "div#mat table {
          table-layout: auto;
        }
        div#mat .matrix-input-col-header-cell div {
          min-width: 100px;
        }"
      ))),

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Min Col Width"),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("numoc", "Number of bins:",
                        min = 1, max = 50, value = 5),
            numericInput("inp1", "Inp1", 1)
        ),

        mainPanel(
           uiOutput("mat") # show the matrix
        )
    )
)

# Server as provided by the asker
server <- function(input, output) {

  output$mat <- renderUI({
    rw <- list(1:input$numoc)
    for (i in (1:input$numoc)) {
      rw[[1]][[i]] <- paste("Outcome", i, sep = " ")
    }
    
    
    clm <- list(1:input$inp1)
    for (i in (1:input$inp1)) {
      clm[[1]][[i]] <- paste("Treatment", i, sep = " ")
    }
    
    matrix1 <- matrix(seq(from=1, to=((input$numoc)*(input$inp1)), by=1), input$inp1, input$numoc, dimnames = list(clm[[1]],rw[[1]]))
    
    matrixInput("mat", "Probabilities", matrix1, rows=list(names=TRUE), cols=list(names=TRUE))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I tested this sample in Firefox and the R-Studio App Viewer.

Comment: That works perfectly! Thanks a lot! I thought there might be a way to override the page width with css but I wasn't sure how. Thanks!